# Simple XML @Text causing exception

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I have a simple class like this:

```
    public static class MyData {

        @Text(required = false)
        protected String value;
        @Attribute(required = true)
        protected String id;

        @Text
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Text
        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String value) {
            this.id = value;
        }
```

}

It is causing an exception:

```
Exception Text annotation 
  @org.simpleframework.xml.Text(data=false, empty=, required=true) 
on method 'value' used with elements in class MyData
```

Actual XML is:

```
  <MyData id="fakeId">An HTTP Link is here</MyData>
```

Any idea:
I have tried to few combinations like not having `@Text` annotation at the getValue/setValue but doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was these annotations before the class.
        @Default(DefaultType.FIELD)
        @Order(elements= {
        })

It worked fine after removing the above lines.